# Joomla wraps content in <p> tags

Tags: html, joomla

I have Joomla 2.5 installed.
I developed some little module which generates html code.
Now, when it outputs the generated code, Joomla wraps it in <p> tags.
This causes two problems: 
1. My css doesn't apply well because of paragraphing.
2. Paragraphs are crossing other tags.
For example here is a part of the module code:

```
<div class="formBlock">
    <div class="label"><?php echo LABEL_PROJ_DESC; ?></div>
    <textarea   class="descbox"
                id="descriptionBox"
                name="rp_proj_desc"
                cols="35" 
                rows="6"><?php echo $sender_description; ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="formBlock">
    <div class="label"><?php echo LABEL_PRODUCTS; ?></div>
    <div class="formTable">
<?php                   
        foreach($products as $id => $product)
        {
            $checked = "";

            foreach($selectedProducts as $selectedId => $name)
            {
                if ($id == $selectedId)
                {
                    $checked = "yes";
                    break;
                }
            }
?>
        <div class="productsRow">
            <span>
                <input  class="formCheckbox"
                        type="checkbox" 
<?php 
                        if ($checked)
                        {
                            echo "checked=yes ";
                        }
?>
                        name="<?php echo PROD_PREFIX . $id; ?>" />
            </span>
            <span class="productsName"><?php echo trim($product); ?></span>
        </div>
<?php
        }
?>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I actually get is:

```
<div class="formBlock">
<div class="label">Your project description:</div>
<p>         <textarea   class="descbox"
                        id="descriptionBox"
                        name="rp_proj_desc"
                        cols="35" 
                        rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
<div class="formBlock">
<div class="label">Our products you interested in:</div>
<div class="formTable">
<div class="productsRow">
                    <span></p>
<input  class="formCheckbox"
                                type="checkbox" 
                                name="product_0" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="productsName">Product1</span>
                </div>
<div class="productsRow">
                    <span></p>
<input  class="formCheckbox"
                                type="checkbox" 
                                name="product_1" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="productsName">Product2</span>
                </div>
<div class="productsRow">
                    <span></p>
<input  class="formCheckbox"
                                type="checkbox" 
                                name="product_2" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="productsName">Cheese</span>
                </div>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Put attention to <p> and </p> tags.
If search amount of <p> and </p> elements in "view source" page it will:
<p> - 12
</p> - 18

It means that something really wrong happening with Joomla...
I guess that it is some plugin influencing it. I listed all plugins, especially those of type - "content" but didn't find any causing the problem.

These are the enabled plugins:

> plg_editors-xtd_article
>
> plg_finder_categories
>
> plg_search_categories
>
> plg_editors_codemirror
>
> Xmap - Content Plugin
>
> plg_finder_contacts
>
> plg_search_contacts
>
> plg_finder_content
>
> plg_search_content
>
> plg_system_debug
>
> plg_content_emailcloak
>
> plg_quickicon_extensionupdate
>
> System - Gantry
>
> plg_content_geshi
>
> plg_system_highlight
>
> plg_editors-xtd_image
>
> Content - ITPShare
>
> Editor - JCE
>
> plg_authentication_joomla
>
> plg_extension_joomla
>
> plg_user_joomla
>
> plg_quickicon_joomlaupdate
>
> System - Jquery
>
> plg_content_loadmodule
>
> plg_system_log
>
> plg_system_logout
>
> AcyMailing Manage text
>
> plg_finder_newsfeeds
>
> plg_search_newsfeeds
>
> plg_editors_none
>
> AcyMailing Tag : Website links
>
> plg_system_p3p
>
> plg_content_pagebreak
>
> plg_editors-xtd_pagebreak
>
> plg_content_pagenavigation
>
> plg_editors-xtd_readmore
>
> plg_captcha_recaptcha
>
> plg_system_redirect
>
> AcyMailing : (auto)Subscribe during Joomla registration
>
> plg_system_remember
>
> System - RokExtender
>
> plg_system_sef
>
> AcyMailing : share on social networks
>
> SIGE
>
> AcyMailing : Statistics Plugin
>
> AcyMailing table of contents generator
>
> AcyMailing Tag : content insertion
>
> AcyMailing Tag : Subscriber information
>
> AcyMailing Tag : Manage the Subscription
>
> AcyMailing Tag : Date / Time
>
> AcyMailing Tag : Joomla User Information
>
> AcyMailing Template Class Replacer
>
> plg_editors_tinymce
>
> plg_content_vote
>
> plg_finder_weblinks
>
> plg_search_weblinks
>
> System - Shortcodes

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!
It was System - Shortcodes plugin of Zauan Shortcodes which distroyed my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's the editor (probably TinyMCE) that inserts these `<p>` tags. You should consider switching to "no editor" option (or another editor) - it can be set under "Global Configuration" screen, in the "Site" tab.
Also, in order to embed PHP code in your articles you should use a plugin such as [DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470).

Comment: Thank you for replay, but disabling of editor didn't solved the problem and I don't use embeded PHP code in article. I use module and load it with {loadposition ...} directive from an article.

Comment: Try the following: go to Extentsions => Plugin Manager => Editor-TinyMCE. In `Parameters` panel, find `New Lines` and change it to `BR Elements`

Comment: If that doesn't work, another thing you can try is to go to `Global Configuration` and disable `Text Filters`. Please let me know if it worked for you. Weird enough, I don't have this problem (also using 2.5) and since I can't reproduce, I also can't test it...

Comment: Thank you for replay. From beggining I disables wiswig editor, but any way I set BR element as element for new lines and disables all filters... Stil have P elements seed in my form...

Comment: By the way I use Ammon tamplete of Hogash: http://www.hogash.com/  I have strong feel that appearance of P not related to editor (again, I disabled it) I think it related to some plugin which came with the installation. By the way I disabled TinyMCE as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the textbox you created is not an RTF field.
If you use RTF field, then

tags would be created automatically.

Comment: The textarea tag may create a RTF field as it is multi line.

Comment: I have <p> tags everywhere outside textarea